# Capitalizing first and last letter in java using String methods

Tags: java, string

I'm a beginner in java and we were asked to that will capitalize the first and last letter of the word.

[Hint: Capture the letter as a string (using the substring method) then use the toUpperCase() method.]

all i have so far is this,

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Excercise6 {
   public static void main (String [] args){

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.print("Please Type a word: ");
    String word = keyboard.nextLine();

    int stringLength = word.length();
   String letter1 = word.substring (0,1);
   String lastletter = word.substring ((stringLength-1),(stringLength));
   String newWord =letter1.toUpperCase() + lastletter.toUpperCase();


    System.out.println("The word with first letter capitalized is: " + newWord );

   }
}
```

How do I add the words between the first and the last letter??

Comment: String lettersBetween = word.substring(1, stringLength - 1) ?

Comment: You seems to know how to take part of string. You simply need to take part after first and before last letter and add it to your upper-versions of first and last characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code looks fine, just make some changes

```
String newWord = letter1.toUpperCase()
                + word.substring(1, word.length() - 1)
                + lastletter.toUpperCase();
```

**First Letter** - `letter1.toUpperCase()`

**Middle String** - `word.substring(1, word.length() - 1)`

**Last Letter** - `lastletter.toUpperCase();`

**output**

```
Please Type a word: ankur
The word with first letter capitalized is: AnkuR
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
String a = "java";
String first = a.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase();
String last = a.substring((a.length() - 1), a.length()).toUpperCase();
String middle = a.substring(1, a.length() - 1);
System.out.println(first + middle + last);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following

```
String letter1 = word.substring (0,1);
String lastletter = word.substring ((stringLength-1),(stringLength));
String newWord =letter1.toUpperCase() + word.subString(1, stringLength-1) + lastletter.toUpperCase();
```

That should give you the "middle" of the word, without the first and last letters

Comment: @Brandon Laidig, it will only give upto 3rd last character

Comment: @ankur-singhal Yes thank you. I had the understanding that substring was inclusive, i.e substring(1,3) would grab characters at index 1, 2, AND 3. Thanks for the correction

Answer (score 0):

The String.[substring()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int)) method will give you a substring.  So split the word into parts like you've partially did:-

```
String startChar = word.substring(0, 1);
String endChar = word.substring(word.length()-1); //If you leave out the last argument, it goes all the way to the end of the String
String middle = word.substring(1, word.length()-1);
```

Then just build your new word (first character, plus middle section, plus last character) and convert the relevant parts ot upper case with the String.[upperCase()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toUpperCase()) method

```
 String newWord = startChar.toUpperCase() + middle + endChar.toUpperCase();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do

```
String st="singhakash";
System.out.println(st.substring(0,1).toUpperCase()+st.substring(1,st.length()-1)+st.substring(st.length()-1).toUpperCase());
```

Output

```
SinghakasH
```

[**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/A4BLN6)

Comment: simply?  That's the least simple way I can think to write that code :P

Answer (score 0):

Since everybody is giving a suggestion that would work; I'm tuning in on a suggestion that would be more efficient and secure.

```
String word = keyboard.nextLine();
```

This does not guarantee a word. It returns a line, which means anything before a newline character '\n'.

To get the words, you should use:

```
String[] words = keyboard.nextLine().split(new char[] { ' ', '\t', '\r' });
```

This will split the line on the characters: space, tab and carriage return (NOTE: not newline).

Next we need to loop through each word with a for-each loop:

```
for(String word : words)
{
int wordLength = word.length(); // Get length, because we're gonna use       it multiple times
if(wordLength > 0) // Ignore empty words
{
    // Only get the first character and convert it to uppercase (better than using substring)
    // Also note that we don't have to check if there's a character at 0, because we already did with wordLength > 0
    char firstCharacter = Character.toUpperCase(word.charAt(0)); 

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(firstCharacter); // We use StringBuilder class because it is efficient in concatenating objects to a string

    if(wordLength == 2) // We only got 2 characters, so no inbetween
    {
        char lastCharacter = Character.toUpperCase(word.charAt(1)); // We know this character is at index 1

        builder.append(lastCharacter); // Append last character
    }
    else // More than 2
    {
        String inbetweenCharacters = word.substring(1, wordLength - 2); // Get the words in between using substring
        char lastCharacter = Character.toUpperCase(word.charAt(wordLength - 1)); // Get the last character

        builder.append(inbetweenCharacters); // Append inbetween characters
        builder.append(lastCharacter); // Append last character
    }

    System.out.println(builder.toString()); // Print complete converted word
}
}
```

I did this on the top of my head, I hope it doesn't have any typos

Answer (score 0):

/** code to add the words of string sentence 1st to last , 2nd to 2ndlast, 3rd to 3rdlast and as on
    author : deependra singh patel*/

import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReverseStringWordConcate {

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter The Sentence");
    String s1 = scn.nextLine();
    String []s2 = s1.split(" ");
    int i1 = 0;
    for(int i =s2.length-1;i>=0;i--) {
        if(s2[i]==s2[i1] ){
            char [] arr = s2[i].toCharArray();
            System.out.print(arr.length+s2[i1]);
            break;
        }
        else {
        //System.out.print(s2[i]+s2[i1]+" ");
        char [] arr = s2[i].toCharArray();
        char arr1[] = s2[i1].toCharArray();
        System.out.print((arr.length+arr1.length)+s2[i]+s2[i1]+" ");

        }
        i1++;
}






}
}
```

/* sample input : deependra singh patel thegun singhraur

```
   expected output :18singhraurdeependra 11thegunsingh 5patel
```

*/